# Handling large dataset in the batch output

Tags: spring-batch

I have a use case where for every input record ( returned by Itemreader ) the processor will produce millions of rows( huge dataset ) which needs to be persisted in a database table

I tried to handle all the inserts in ItemWriter but before even it reaches ItemWriter for the step, i am getting out of memory. I have only one step in my Job

How to handle the persistence of large dataset as output in the spring batch step ?

Note: local chunking is something i could not use here as the input with just one record for which it is failing

Comment: do you mean the processor goes to out of memory while it processes first reader record?

Comment: the processor creates 1 million records for one reader record. I expect the 1 million rows to be written to the database using the ItemWriter. But processor while creating those collection of objects goes out of memory. I cannot batch between processor and writer as chunking doesn't work that way

Comment: How many input records do you have? The solution may depend on the size of input records.

Comment: The input record is few 100's. Just to re-iterate for 1 input record the processor logic will generate 1 million output transactions. If i can solve this for 1 input record processor, should be good enough